# no me inserta la imagen blob pero si me la lee cuando la inserto desde la bbdd

Tags: php, html, pdo

estoy insertando un archivo blob de formato png a la bd, pero desde el formulario no me la inserta y no la convierte a binario, dejo el código abajo y la foto para que veais que realmente el campo esta definido como blob, puede ser que sea por tener el valor null en no ?
Gracias un saludo.

***Este es el que genera el image/png;base64***

```
<?php
include '../../config/conexion.php';
$query_contactos = $bd->query("SELECT contactos.id_contactos AS id_contactos,contactos.id_categoria AS id_categoria, contactos.nombre AS nombre,contactos.apellido_1 
    as apellido_1,contactos.apellido_2 as apellido_2,contactos.telefono as telefono,
    contactos.email as email,categorias.nombre as categoria,contactos.foto AS foto
    FROM t_contactos AS contactos
    INNER JOIN t_categorias AS categorias ON contactos.id_categoria = categorias.id_categoria");
$t_contactos = $query_contactos->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
//print_r($t_contactos);
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../dependencias/font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
    <title>Lista de Contactos</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <h3 id="mostrar">Lista de Contactos</h3>
            <table class="table table-dark table-striped table-hover">
                <tr>
                    <td>#</td>
                    <td>Nombre</td>
                    <td>Apellido 1</td>
                    <td>Apellido 2</td>
                    <td>Teléfono</td>
                    <td>Email</td>
                    <td>Categoria</td>
                    <td>Foto</td>
                    <td>Accion 1</td>
                    <td>Accion 2</td>
                </tr>
                <?php foreach ($t_contactos as $fila_C) { ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $fila_C->id_contactos; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $fila_C->nombre; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $fila_C->apellido_1; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $fila_C->apellido_2; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $fila_C->telefono; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $fila_C->email; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $fila_C->categoria; ?></td>
                        <td><img src="data:image/png;base64, <?php echo base64_encode($fila_C->foto); ?>"></td>
                        <td>
                            <span>
                                <form action="editar.php" method="post">
                                    <input name="id" hidden="hidden" value="<?php echo $fila_C->id_contactos; ?>">
                                    <input name="id_categoria" hidden="hidden" value="<?php echo $fila_C->id_categoria; ?>">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    <i class="fa fa-pencil-square"></i> 
                                </form>
                            </span>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <form action="../procesos/tabla_contactos/eliminarProceso.php" method="post">
                                <input name="id" hidden="hidden" value="<?php echo $fila_C->id_contactos; ?>">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">
                                <i class="fa fa-trash"></i> 
                            </button>
                            </form>
                            
                        <?php } ?>
                        
                    </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>

    
</body>

</html>
```

***Este el que inserta los datos***

```
<?php 
    include '../../config/conexion.php';

    try {
        $query_categorias = $bd->query("SELECT * FROM t_categorias");
        $query_categorias->execute();
        $t_categorias = $query_categorias->fetchAll();
        //print_r($t_categorias);
    } catch (PDOException $eMostrarC) {
        echo "Error en la sentencia : ".$eMostrarC->getMessage();
    }
    
    try {
         
        $query_usuarios = $bd->query("SELECT * FROM t_usuarios");
        $query_usuarios->execute();
        $t_usuarios = $query_usuarios->fetchAll();
        //print_r($t_usuarios);
    } catch (PDOException $eMostrarU) {
        echo "Error en la sentencia : ".$eMostrarU->getMessage();
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    
    <title>Insertar Contactos</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h3 class="insertar">Insertar Contactos</h3>
        <form action="../procesos/tabla_contactos/insertarProceso.php"  method="POST" enctype='multipart/form-data'>

        <label for="categorias">Categorias</label>
        <select name="categoriaSelect">
        <?php foreach($t_categorias as $fila_c) : 
            echo '<option value="'.$fila_c['id_categoria'].'">'.$fila_c['nombre'].'</option>';
         endforeach; ?>
        </select>

        <label for="usuarioAsignado">Asignar Usuario</label>
        <select name="usuarioAsignado">
        <?php foreach($t_usuarios as $fila_u) :  
            echo '<option value="'.$fila_u['id_usuarios'].'">'.$fila_u['nombre'].'</option>';
         endforeach; ?>
        </select><br>
            
            <label for="nombre">Nombre</label>
            <input type="text" name="nombre">

            <label for="apellido_1">Apellido 1</label>
            <input type="text" name="apellido_1">

            <label for="apellido_2">Apellido 2</label>
            <input type="text" name="apellido_2">

            <label for="telefono">Teléfono</label>
            <input type="text" name="telefono">

            <label for="email">Email</label>
            <input type="text" name="email">

            <label for="imagen">Foto</label>
            <input type="file" name="foto" size="20">

            <input type="hidden" name="insertar_contacto" value="1">
            <input type="submit" value="Insertar Contacto">
        </form>
</body>
</html>
```

***Y este el que procesa los datos del formulario insertar***

```
<?php 
    include '../../../config/Conexion.php';
    //print_r($_POST);
    if(!isset($_POST['insertar_contacto'])){
        exit();
    }

    try {
        $selectCategoria = $_POST['categoriaSelect'];
        $usuarioAsignado = $_POST['usuarioAsignado'];
        $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
        $apellido_1 = $_POST['apellido_1'];
        $apellido_2 = $_POST['apellido_2'];
        $telefono = $_POST['telefono'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $foto = base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES['foto']['tmp_name']));

        $query_insertar = $bd->prepare("INSERT INTO t_contactos
         (id_categoria,id_usuarios,nombre,apellido_1,apellido_2,telefono,email,foto)
        VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);");
        $resultado = $query_insertar->execute([$selectCategoria,$usuarioAsignado,$nombre,$apellido_1,$apellido_2,$telefono,$email,$foto]);
        

        if($resultado === true){
          header('Location: ../../vista_de_contactos/listar_contactos.php');
        }
    } catch (PDOException $eInsertar) {
        echo "Error al ejecutar el insert <br>".$eInsertar->getMessage();
    }
?>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No entiendo cuál es el problema. ¿Es que la imagen no se inserta en la BD? ¿Es que luego de insertada no puedes mostrarla en un HTML? ¿Hay algún error? ¿Cuál? ¿Qué flujo sigue el código?

Comment: Hola el caso es que la inserta pero no como un archivo blob como se puede apreciar cuando la inserto desde la bd en su campo correspondiente si la lee correctamente, es desde el formulario.

Comment: En la captura de pantalla se ve que sí la inserta como un BLOB, se lee `BLOB` y al lado el tamaño de la imagen. ¿Por qué dices que no la inserta como BLOB?

Comment: por que el ultimo usuario el 13 es el insertado desde el formulario y desde el formulario no lo inserta como tal pero aunque la inserte no logro entender por que no la lee como es debido.

Comment: No logro entenderte. ¿Qué verificaciones has hecho para decir que *no lo inserta como es debido*? ¿Qué flujo sigue tu código: si redirige, a qué página, si da error, qué error? Considera que no estamos en tu mente ni frente a tu pantalla y por tanto debes explicar las cosas con la mayor claridad posible. Si hablas del usuario 13 ¿por qué no muestras captura de los datos que tiene el usuario 13?

Comment: te he añadido una captura de la foto insertada para que veas el codigo blob que inserta en el value.

Comment: En el código que muestras en la pregunta no veo por ninguna parte donde se estaría creando ese elemento `img` que es el que al parecer tiene problema.

Comment: Hola A.Cedano es verdad que no te estaba mostrando la tabla donde generaba el images/png y la etiqueta img, como puedes observar ahi te la muestro corregida y mejor ordenada a ver si así aclaro dudas, un saludo !

Comment: Si lo codificas a base 64 no tiene sentido usar BLOB, es mas fácil que cambies la columna a CLOB. Si mantienes la columna como BLOB tienes que cambiar la forma de vincular el parámetro, por que prácticamente lo estás manejando como una cadena y no como datos binarios.

Comment: ok gracias Sal probaré en un rato y os comento el resultado :)

Comment: en el gestor de bbdd no está esa opción de clob se puede alterar esa columna sin más ? lo estoy haciendo con mysql.

Comment: ¿Tú estás seguro de que la imagen es `.png`?

Comment: si es png por que lo dices ?

Comment: El tipo debería ser `TEXT`.

Comment: Pregunto lo de `.png` porque aquí `data:image/png;base64` le estás indicando ese mime-type, pero si la imagen es de otro tipo: `jpg, gif`, etc, te va a fallar por usar un mime-type que no es el suyo. Debes asegurarte de que realmente es `.png`. Por otro lado te aconsejo que revises tu log de errores, allí tendrás sin duda información útil para saber con exactitud lo que está pasando.